# Recommended Process Modeling Software Tool

Tags: text-processing, modeling

I'm looking a process modeling software tool that has different functionality.

This software should enable to support and define a business process throughout the organization's function and people's occupation.

I also need to define the size of the organization's size, function and people by using a functionality.
When you click on a button you are enable to see a business process from the beginning and all the end throughout the functions and people.

You also should enable to define people's usage of data that is used from another person. You should enable to see this person's usage of data is used and taken from another person.

It is good that this application has functionality to create data dictionary and data flow diagram.

I strongly believe that this software tool is used by business analyst, system analyst, business intelligence analyst or data analyst.

My questions are:

- What software tool can you recommend me to use?
- Is there a tool that has a similar requirement as above?

Comment: Which specific types of business processes do you need to model?

Comment: I need to make a modeling for instance this incoming order needs to be valid about the price and then it will be sent to the right person.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/nickmalik/WindowsLiveWriter/BlametheComputerABusinessProcessModeling_F4AC/Automated%20Process%20Example2_2.png

This picture shows a concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

Try Gliffy

Each BPMN element — flow object, connecting object, swimlane, and artifact — is represented by a shape. Drag and drop these shapes from the Gliffy library into a diagram that depicts how data, activities, and groups are associated. Gliffy delivers the BPMN tools you need to help stakeholders get a clear picture of your business process. Hope this was helpful

http://www.gliffy.com/uses/business-process-modeling-software/